# Getting rid of Whitespace in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, crop

Is there a way in Inkscape to set the boundaries of the svg file the way they would be set if you export as a bitmap?

I want that there's no whitespace above, beneath, right or left of the object that I select.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

In the latest version of Inkscape (0.92.2 at this time), you can go to **Edit** → **Resize Page to Selection** or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.

Answer (score 113):

To modify the document bounding box:

1. Go to **File** → ***Document Properties...*** (or press <kbd>Shift</kbd> +<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>)
2. In the **Custom size** area on the Page tab, expand ***Resize Page to content...*** (or press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>)
3. Click the ***Resize page to drawing or selection*** button (or press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>)

You can add margins if you like

[image: Document properties dialog]

Comment: With the latest version, I cannot see this option.

Comment: @bim does [this other answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/118189/8708) work for you in the latest version?

Comment: Yes, that is working  and I am using that. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Another way is to make a keyboard shorcut by going to Edit -> Preferences -> Interface -> Keyboard Shorcuts and searching for

"fitcanvastoselectionordraw"

You should find the "Fit Page to Selection Or Drawing" there.

Left click the shortcut column (blank space) to assign a shortcut.