# inkscape padding or margin on export

Tags: inkscape

How can I add padding or margin easily when exporting drawing or selection to bitmap?

What I've been doing is changing the width and x, y values when exporting but it's a lot of work when exporting many selections one by one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [**Getting rid of Whitespace in Inkscape**](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/21638/8708) As noted, you can add margins as you resize the page

Comment: @JohnB: Very good solution, better than using the selected solution, at least in some cases.

Comment: I'm tempted to just add margins with Imagemagick: https://askubuntu.com/questions/819482/how-to-add-a-border-using-imagemagick

Answer (score 7):

I simply mark the whole drawing, and resize the page to it, so that the page has the desired margin to the drawing. I nearly always use page format A4 landscape or A4 portrait with visible page border.

[image]

While bitmap exporting, I can easily choose between drawing, page or selection.

Comment: It doesn't seem like this is still possible in Inkscape 1.2, at least not in the same location.

Comment: [How to add canvas margins to canvas in Inkscape 1.2](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/157449/26474)

Answer (score 5):

Another technique is to use several rectangles used for cropping/exporting:

- Create a new layer, called Export for example. Place it beneath other layers.
- In this layer, create rectangles that will define what areas you will want to crop/export. Maybe white rectangles beneath your objects.
- Export each rectangle individually: select a rectangle, go to `File > Export bitmap` (or Ctrl-E), en choose `Selection` before exporting.
- When you need to make modifications, you can either export a rectangle individually, or **all at once** (Select them all - the export dialogue box has a `Batch export all selected objects` option). But exporting them once beforehand will determine their location and file name.

Tip: If you don't want have visible rectangles when exporting, you can select them, then hide them by hiding the export layer (*but the rectangles will still be selected*), then export them.

Answer (score 2):

Draw a rectangle over the area you want to export. Make the rectangle have transparant fill. Select the rectangle and export the selection

Answer (score 0):

If you want a border of, say, *100px* around your selection/document:

- add a reclangle, put its

  - position: 0, 0,
  - size: doc-width, doc-height,
  - fill: transparent, border: transparent
  - bodrer-size: *100px*
- select all (Ctrl+A)
- export selection