# Cropping SVG files

Tags: inkscape, svg, crop

How do I crop SVG files I created used MarvinSketch? Now I realise there are a few answers to this question like this one [Getting rid of Whitespace in Inkscape](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21635/getting-rid-of-whitespace-in-inkscape) but I've done that and it didn't work as there was still some space left in the image. Plus, for some reason there's a white background behind every letter in the image, even though MarvinSketch doesn't create SVGs with this white background. This too I would like to be able to fix, if possible.

[SVG prior to cropping](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1_sXH68hMWBYWg1b0VkUkJKRXM/edit?usp=sharing)

[SVG after cropping](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1_sXH68hMWBZTRlQ2Z5ZzF6SXM/edit?usp=sharing)

By the way I'd be more than happy to use another software than Inkscape, provided it's free and available on Ubuntu. I would like this method to be more than just adjusting the page width and height as this is subject to a lot of user error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just saw your question on AskUbuntu and I think you should give Inkscape another try. Converting to PNG and back to SVG really isn't the right way to go about this.

I took a closer look at the SVG files you posted and I think I might have found what's causing the extra whitespace around the image. It looks like MarvinSketch is adding some extra spaces to the functional groups:

[image]

Removing these is quite easy:

1. Ungroup the diagram by clicking on it and pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>. You might have to do this multiple times depending on how the elements were grouped when the SVG file was created. I had to ungroup your sample file twice.
2. Select one of the functional groups with the selection tool (standard mouse pointer, can be activated with <kbd>F1</kbd>)
3. Press <kbd>F8</kbd> to enter the text editing mode
4. Delete the extra spaces
5. Repeat the last three steps for each functional group
6. Follow the instructions provided in the Q&A you linked to resize the canvas to the image

The image should now be cropped properly:

[image]

Of course it would be preferable to instruct MarvinSketch not to add these spaces in the first place. I am not familiar with the application but you might want to look around in the settings and see if there's any way to change this.

---

**Edit**

I guess you already found your answer but just for posterity's sake here's what's actually going on behind the scenes.

If you open your SVG file in a text editor you will find the following passage:

```xml
  <text xml:space="preserve" x="605" y="327" clip-path="url(#clipPath1)" stroke="none">N
  </text>
  <text xml:space="preserve" x="117" y="608" clip-path="url(#clipPath1)" stroke="none">OH
  </text>
```

The issue lies with the newline after the text value, i.e. `N` and `OH`, respectively. If you remove the newline like so...:

```
  <text xml:space="preserve" x="605" y="327" clip-path="url(#clipPath1)" stroke="none">N</text>
  <text xml:space="preserve" x="117" y="608" clip-path="url(#clipPath1)" stroke="none">OH</text>
```

...the extra whitespace disappears.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out, or at least one way of doing it. Firstly, I use **MarvinSketch to create a large PNG file** (so as to avoid too much pixelation to occur), then I crop it using **GIMP** (by going to `Image->Autocrop Image`; which is more effective in removing wasted space in PNGs than Inkscape is for SVG files), then (after installing **Inkscape**, of course), I **executed the following code** from **terminal**:

```
cd ~/Directory_of_Input_files/
/usr/bin/inkscape -z -f Input.png -w image-width -e Output.svg
```

Comment: This just creates an SVG which contains an embedded PNG picture, which is completely pointless.

Answer (score 0):

### Automated Solution

*Based on information from Glutanimate's answer.*

1. Create style sheet to strip that white space in text nodes

   `strip-spaces.xslt`

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

       <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
         <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
         </xsl:copy>
       </xsl:template>

       <xsl:template match="text()"><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/></xsl:template>

   </xsl:stylesheet>
   ```
2. Use `xsltproc` to process it

   ```
   xsltproc -o output.svg strip-spaces.xslt input.svg
   ```
3. Crop it using inkscape

   ```
   inkscape --verb=FitCanvasToDrawing --verb=FileSave --verb=FileClose output.svg
   ```

You can write script for this.

What I'm missing, inkscape should have pure CLI (without launching GUI). it may need a bug report.

```
# doesn't crop

inkscape -z -f output.svg -D -l output2.svg

# works well going to eps,ps but going back to svg, it has a deflect

inkscape -z -f output.svg -D -E output3.eps
inkscape -z -f output3.eps -D -l output2.svg

inkscape -z -f output.svg -D -P output4.ps
inkscape -z -f output4.ps -D -l output2.svg
```

**References:**

- [XSLT: `<xsl:strip-space>` does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134318/xslt-xslstrip-space-does-not-work)
- [Inkscape - cropping SVG files on the Command Line](https://shkspr.mobi/blog/2013/03/inkscape-cropping-svg-files-on-the-command-line/)