# Is it possible to resize the page interactively in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, workflow, shortcuts, canvas, document-setup

I would like to resize the page interactively in Inkscape, either with the mouse or with a keyboard shortcut. Is this possible?

If it were not possible, could this potentially be a desirable feature, or are there good practical reasons not to implement it?

Comment: Welcome on GD.SE, mgarort. Can you be more specific, please? I don't know if is it proper to talk about canvas in SVG, are you perhaps referring to the page size? See [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21635/getting-rid-of-whitespace-in-inkscape) and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46195427/inkscape-fit-page-to-selection-shortcut).

Comment: Draw a rectangle, then hit Shift+Ctrl+R, which will fit the page to the selection.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.Yes, I mean page size. I was picturing something more along the lines of dragging the corners of the page, but resizing to selection as explained in the links provided also works. Thanks!

Comment: There's nothing in Inkscape that allows you to click and drag the page itself. You need to draw a rectangle, then hit the shortcut. Obviously you could resize the rectangle by clicking and dragging, but then you'd need to use the shortcut again to fit the page to it.

Comment: So, basically the answer to your question is no, but there's a workaround.  As to whether being able to click and drag the page would be helpful, I guess so, but the workaround is rather easy anyway.  I could see this being useful if Inkscape had multipage support, but it doesn't, and neither does the SVG format.